# Filtering a dictionary to contain values from another dictionary that meet certain criteria

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to create a new dict which has only filtered values from another dict that contain tweets with 50 or more characters. I can't figure what to use to add to this new dict

I tried using .update but that only seemed to add the final tweet after the for loop to the new dict

```
def is_short_tweet(tweet):
    if len(tweet) < 50:
        return True
    else:
        return False

1_filtered = dict()

for i in 1_tweets: 
    if not is_short_tweet(i["text"]):
        1_filtered.update(i) """ what do I use here to add to the new, filtered dict?"""
```

Comment: `1_filtered` is an illegal identifier.

Comment: variables should not start with any number

Comment: Can you share an example `dict` you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing the `tweets` variable is a list of dictionaries, not one dictionary. (Which didn't make sense to me according to the code you showed).

As you said you want to keep **multiple** tweet**s** with more than 50 characters length, you may want to use **a list of** dictionaries.

```
def is_short_tweet(tweet):
    if len(tweet) < 50:
        return True
    else:
        return False

filtered = []  # define filtered as a list, instead of dictionary

for i in tweets: 
    if not is_short_tweet(i["text"]):
        filtered.append(i)  # use append() to add i (which is a dictionary ) to the list
```

Note about `.update()` method of dictionaries:

> The update() method adds element(s) to the dictionary if the key is not in the dictionary. If the key is in the dictionary, it updates the key with the new value.

So as you had same keys for each tweet, what you were doing was to update this information with the latest long tweet found.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `dict` comprehension to do filtering:

```
d = {1:'a'*49, 2:'b'*50, 3:'c'*51}
#{1: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
# 2: 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
# 3: 'ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'}

filtered = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(v)>=50}
```

Output:

```
{2: 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
 3: 'ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'}
```